# Rails Heroku App won't Load (Error Code =H10) Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Everything was fine with my Heroku app deployment for the duration of my following the rails tutorial on [railstutorial.org/](https://www.railstutorial.org/) by Michael Hartl until I got to chapter 13 (Microposts). I meticulously followed the guides. However, on app deployment, I get this error

> Application error An error occurred in the application and your page
>   could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs
>   for details.

I have `reset` the database, run `migrate` and `seed` several times over as suggested by solutions offered to similar issues and yet with no luck. Here is the log file sample:

```
2018-05-18T22:14:48.676937+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 10900 -e production`
2018-05-18T22:14:54.060567+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960648+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.2.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:78:in `eval': uninitialized constant CarrierWave::Storage::Fog (NameError)
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960656+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.2.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:78:in `eval'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960657+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.2.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:78:in `storage'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960661+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/app/uploaders/picture_uploader.rb:8:in `<class:PictureUploader>'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960662+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/app/uploaders/picture_uploader.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960664+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960665+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:149:in `exclusive'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960666+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960668+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/app/models/micropost.rb:4:in `<class:Micropost>'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960669+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/app/models/micropost.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960670+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960709+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:149:in `exclusive'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960763+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960765+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:476:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960767+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960769+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `block in eager_load!'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960854+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `each'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960857+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `eager_load!'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960858+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:354:in `eager_load!'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960860+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:67:in `each'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960861+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:67:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960867+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960868+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960870+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960871+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960873+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960874+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960876+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960877+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960881+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960883+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960884+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960887+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960888+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960889+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960892+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960893+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960894+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960897+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960898+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960900+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:in `new'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960901+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:in `<main>'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960904+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960905+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960907+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960908+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960911+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960913+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:24:in `app'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960914+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960917+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:283:in `start'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960919+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:44:in `start'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960920+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `block in perform'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960922+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960924+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960926+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960928+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960935+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960938+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960939+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960941+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960944+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.960945+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2018-05-18T22:14:53.970120+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2018-05-18T22:14:53.970122+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.1.4 application starting in production
2018-05-18T22:14:53.970124+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2018-05-18T22:14:53.970125+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2018-05-18T22:14:54.042883+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-05-18T22:15:16.572035+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-05-18T22:37:55.303199+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=stark-lowlands-20410.herokuapp.com request_id=0c17f93e-2b8d-4836-9918-d6cb6300c67f fwd="137.50.176.88" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-05-18T22:38:01.314179+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stark-lowlands-20410.herokuapp.com request_id=ace627d1-ff26-4003-8e42-119c266420b8 fwd="137.50.176.88" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Somehow I think it has something to do with the image resize code here (initializers/skip_image_resizing.rb):

```
if Rails.env.test?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.enable_processing = false
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You might find [this issue](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/2228) helpful.

Comment: Ru using carrierwave

Comment: Does it work when you run your server locally with `rails server`?

Comment: @Mic, yes it works just fine on the local server. No Issues at all. Everything goes wrong on Heroku